# How to validate password strength with Devise in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords

I want to force a user to choose a strong password on registration.

I know, there are many jquery password strength meters out there, and I will most probably use one of them, too. But that does not really enforce anyone to choose a strong password. The registration form must also be useable without js enabled, so one could still potentially register with a weak password.

Accounts must be most secure, because if you are logged in, you can see data of other accounts, which I do not want exposed under any circumstances. So I want to go for maximum security here, therefore I think, it is most important to only allow strong passwords.

So,

**How do I set and customize requirements for validating minimum password strength? Only thing I could find in the devise config file is password length. Is there another gem that I should use for this task?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [Devise Security extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension), where you can define a password regexp validation (among other things) and enforce the password strength you want.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll give it a try. Though, I haven't seen the [regex syntax used in the config file](http://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension#configuration) before. `(?=...)` I see what it does, but I would appreciate a little explanation, what the `?`'s mean.

Comment: IMHO these tests are too naive; it just wants a number & capital letter. A very long password with no numbers is still secure, but `Passw0rd` (for example) is a piss poor password (yet still meets these requirements)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker is right; trying to do password strength by matching regular expressions is an awful idea.

Answer (score 9):

I've recently released a devise gem which uses the zxcvbn library to reject weak passwords:

https://github.com/bitzesty/devise_zxcvbn

Comment: Be warned that this ends up using ExecJS - that's a surprising dependency.

Comment: @jamesmoore this was needed as the pure Ruby version of the zxcvbn algorithm wasn't returning the same results as the JS version, we switched so that we could get the same results on the front and the backend.

Comment: Interesting - definitely a design tradeoff here.  I'd much rather have no js dependency and get slightly different results (and just do it all on the server, so client-side results would be irrelevant), but it makes sense that some people need the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing (2018), I'd suggest folks consider the newer [Devise Security](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security) fork before settling on the previously recommended [Devise Security extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension) gem (stale as of v0.10.0 March 2016).